# Quelle est l'origine des phrases qui sont écrites sous forme abrégée dans les SMS ?

Tags: ressources, argot, origine-ou-raison, sms-lingo

Je me suis rendu compte qu'il y a quelques phrases (sous forme abrégée) qui sont utilisées dans les SMS.

**Quelle est l'origine de ces phrases ?**

Est-ce qu'il y a une entreprise ou un groupe qui les fait ? Peut-être que ces phrases sont établies par les utilisateurs de l'Internet ou du SMS ?

J'aimerais aussi savoir s'il y a une source pour apprendre la véritable signification de ces phrases.

Comment: Je vis en Iran. Je n'ai pas accès aux SMS en français., J'ai besoin de connaître les phrancofon s'utilisent de quelle les phrase sous forme abrégée dans leurs SMS

Comment: @Shahgholi.Ardalan Ahhhh je vois.  Je vais essayer de réviser votre question pour clarifier.

Comment: @ Patrick Sebastien , merci

Comment: Dans de rares cas, le style SMS aboutit à un rallongement ; ainsi, _au fait_ devient _au faite_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C’est l’usage qui crée ce type d’abréviation. Le but est probablement à l’origine d’économiser d’une part le nombre de caractères (160 par SMS, longtemps facturés par message) et d’autre part le temps de frappe (écrire avec un clavier de téléphone était long).

Si ces abréviations ne sont pas codifiées, elles souvent sont le fruits :

1. de suppressions de lettre, qui correspond plutôt à des mots courants ; par exemple :

   - *bjr* pour « **b**on**j**ou**r** »,
   - *slt* pour « **s**a**l**u**t** »,
   - *stp* pour « **s**’il **t**e **p**laît » (courant dans tout type d’écrit court),
   - *bcp* pour « **b**eau**c**ou**p** » ;
2. d’écriture phonétique, comme

   - *O* pour « au »
   - *1* pour « un » ou « une »,
   - *fé* pour « fais » ( / ! \ prononcé *fè*, /fɛ/)
   - *C* [prononcé *sé* /se/] pour « c’est » ( / ! \ prononcé *sè* /sɛ/),
   - *T* [prononcé *té* /te/] pour « t’es », lui même forme familière de « tu es »,
   - *TT* [prononcé tété /tete/] pour « t’étais » ( / ! \ à prononcer *tétè* /tetɛ/), « tu étais »,
   - *bi1*, [à découper en *bi-1*, *bi-un*] pour « bien »,
   - *Kdo* [à découper en *K-do*, *ca-do*] pour « cadeau ».
   - *6né* [à découper en *6-né*, *si-né*] pour « ciné », forme familière de cinéma.

Dans ce second cas, la meilleure chose à faire est bien souvent de les prononcer à haute voix (la difficulté étant parfois de savoir où découper le mot). Il faut remarquer qu’*il est fréquent d’écrire en majuscule les lettres à prononcer comme dans un alphabet* (*B* se lit *bé* /be/, *C* se lit *sé* /se/, …).

Une recherche sur l’internet du terme « dictionnaire SMS » donne quelques résultats qui te seront peut-être utiles. En voici un où j’ai puisé quelques exemples : http://dictionnaire-sms.com/.