# Quelles sont les abréviations usuelles dans le langage SMS ?

Tags: orthographe, sms-lingo, abréviations

J'ai lu beaucoup d'abréviations ici :

http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-texting.htm

J'ai vu sur internet des mots dans cette liste, par exemple « pcque » et « bsr ». Et il y en a d'autres que je n'ai pas vus, comme « 2 » pour « deux ».

En anglais, il y a une sociologie très complexe des abréviations : la plupart ne sont pas seulement informelles, mais aussi enfantines. Donc on ne les utilise pas, même dans des situations très informelles avec de bons amis. Mais il y en a d'autres que tout le monde utilise. Par exemple, je n'utiliserais jamais « u » pour « you », même avec mes amis, mais j'utilise « btw » tout le temps. Donc, est-ce acceptable d'utiliser la plupart des mots de cette liste en texting avec des amis ? Ou est-ce que ça semblerait enfantin ?

Comment: Alors c'est une grande question à laquelle (selon moi) il est difficile de répondre. Il faut remarquer que les abréviations pourraient sembler enfantin ou non aux tranches d'âge variées.  Par exemple, je suis anglophone.  Ma mère m'envoie les SMS qui ont des abrévs anglaises lesquelles les jeunes adultes ne utilise pas depuis longtemps (lorsqu'ils étaient ados, enfants, etc). (J'ai 21 ans, elle a 50 ans).  Ces SMS me semblent enfantins seulement parce que je les ai utilisés lorsque j'étais jeune. Il existe aussi les abrévs que je n'ai jamais utilisées, mais........

Comment: mais elles sont très ordinaires dans son tranche d'âge. Cela dit, vous pourriez regarder [cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/quelle-est-lorigine-des-phrases-qui-sont-ecrites-sous-forme-abregee-dans-les-sm) pour des renseignements généraux, mais au moment je pense que cette question est trop "opinion-based" alors je vote à fermer.

Comment: Il me semble que tu as assez de contenu pertinent pour en faire une réponse, Patrick :-)

Comment: @RomainVALERI lol peut-être tu as raison, mais je ne peux pas répondre à la question explicite.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien a 1337 points! Il ne faut pas lui en donner ni lui en enlever! :P Mais je suis d'accord que cela pourrait faire une réponse.

Answer (score 4):

Il faut distinguer deux choses :

1. les abréviations,
2. le langage SMS.

Une abréviation est une manière de raccourcir l'écriture d'un mot, généralement en omettant certaines lettres. Elle **tient compte de l'orthographe correcte** du mot. Elles ont deux usages principaux :

- prendre des notes plus rapidement,
- gagner de la place, par exemple dans des sms **familiers**.

Certaines abréviations extrêmement courantes telles que celles citées par Pierre (càd, qqn, rdv, ràs, etc) peuvent même être admises dans des emails, familiers à nouveau.

Le langage SMS utilise des associations phonétiques pour raccourcir le texte, **sans tenir compte de l'orthographe** des mots raccourcis. Il est essentiellement utilisé entre ados et n'est généralement pas accepté dans d'autres milieux.
À titre d'exemple, j'ai 25 ans et recevoir un SMS en langage SMS de la part d'un adulte me choque énormément.

Une large majorité des expressions de ta liste sont du langage SMS, j'en déconseille donc l'usage.

Pour terminer, voici quelques exemples d'abréviations que j'utilise régulièrement : 
qd (=quand), pr (=pour), vx (=veux), px (=peux), ss (=sans ou suis), tt (=tout), ts (=tous), ds (=dans), qqs (=quelques), ac (=avec), dc (=donc), ns (=nous), vs (=vous), tps (=temps), pdt (=pendant ou pomme de terre), ms (=mais), -mt (= -ment).

Answer (score 2):

En français aussi, il y a des abréviations qui seront jugées infantiles. Tu ne peux pas utiliser la plupart des mots de cette liste qui paraîtront enfantins. Quelques-uns cependant, si ils sont informels, pourront être utilisés sans risque:

- c-à-d
- cdlmt
- qqn
- rdv
- ras
- etc

Tu pourras tout simplement réutiliser ceux que tu rencontreras, ou encore mieux: ne pas en utiliser (ce qui sera toujours bien vu).

Answer (score 1):

L'usage d'abréviations abaisse le niveau de language de ce que vous écrivez. Les plus courantes, listées ci-dessus par Pierre, peuvent être acceptées dans un texte non-littéraire qui s'adresse à un interlocuteur connu : par exemple, dans un email entre collègues ou amis. Elles sont bien sûr plus acceptables dans des messages sur le téléphone portable, à cause des écrans plus petits, des claviers moins fournis et surtout du fait qu'en général, on texte des proches, donc le niveau de language est moins formel.

Attention donc à ne pas utiliser d'abréviations dans un contexte formel.  Par exemple, "cdlmt" veut dire "cordialement", ce qui est en soi une formule de politesse ajoutée à la fin d'un message. La réduire à une abréviation reviendrait à annuler son effet.

Si vous écrivez un article, un texte, un devoir pour l'école ou l'université, les abréviations sont interdites. Si vous écrivez un message à quelqu'un qui n'est ni un ami, ni quelqu'un du même niveau social et professionnel que vous (un collègue du même service, un étudiant d'une même classe), évitez les abréviations.

Il vaut mieux être trop poli ou trop correct en français, ça ne vous sera jamais reproché. Par contre, si vous n'êtes pas assez poli ou si votre niveau de language dénote dans un contexte formel, vous serez mal vu ; mieux vaut simplement éviter les abréviations et, avec elles, les ennuis.