# envoi de textes avec des onomatopées

Tags: onomatopées

I found a friend to learn French with (we are both native English speakers). We text each other and I am wondering if there are French versions of common texting onomatopoeias. Here are the ones I use most often:

- haha – for laughing
- hmmm – for thinking
- wow – for amazement
- errr – for frustration
- ahhh – for understanding
- psh – for being dismissive

Comment: The goal is to communicate information that is naturally transmitted between people through non-verbal channels

Comment: Voici une liste intéressante où vous pouvez piger ce qui vous plait: http://www.les-onomatopees.fr/liste-onomatopees.php

Comment: Voir aussi [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Onomatop%C3%A9es_en_fran%C3%A7ais) et [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatop%C3%A9e#Liste_non_exhaustive_d.27onomatop.C3.A9es). Aussi la question sur les [abréviations](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9141/3177) sous SMS. Merci !

Comment: @Max D: je suis intrigué par votre utilisation de "piger", je suppose que c'est dans le sens de "prendre, piocher" ? De quel pays ou région êtes-vous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are French equivalents I use when texting or messaging my friends - just note you might come across some alternate spellings:

haha – for laughing

hmmm – for thinking

Ouaouh/waouh/waou/waw – for amazement

Grrr/aaargh – for frustration

aaaah – for  understanding

bof - for expressing a feeling of disappointment or lack of enthusiasm for something (ex: "pizza ce soir ? - bof, pas envie, j'en ai déjà mangé hier" "comment était le concert hier soir ? - bof, pas génial")

pff - for expressing you are feeling let down or you are feeling a bit downhearted (ex: "hé, tu viens boire un verre ce soir ? -pff... pas possible, je dois travailler" "youpie, je pars en vacances ce soir ! Je penserai à toi quand je serai sur la plage ! - pfff, arrête, c'est pas drôle, je suis jaloux")

euh (or euuuuh with multiple "u" to tell it is a long "euh"): for expressing a moment of doubt (ex: "sais-tu à quelle heure part notre train -euuuuuh... attends, je ne sais plus, je vais vérifier")

As you can see, some are common to English or quite 
close.

Comment: I think your answer covers it thank you! By the way here is an example of psh: a friend says "we should get burritos" I might say "psh I ate a burrito yesterday. Let's get pizza!"

Comment: OK, then I'll edit my answer, I had another understanding about what you meant by being dismissive.

Comment: @user1834536: *bof, des burritos, j'en ai mangé hier, mais de la pizza: miam miam!*